# name of Lie group $\text{SU}(2) \times \text{SU}(2) \times \text{SU}(2)/\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Once I read a paper in which the author(s) gave a sensible (possibly well-established) name to the $9$-dimensional compact Lie group
$$\frac{\text{SU}(2) \times \text{SU}(2) \times \text{SU}(2)}{\mathbb{Z}_2} \cong \frac{\text{Sp}(1) \times \text{Sp}(1) \times \text{Sp}(1)}{\mathbb{Z}_2}.$$
I can't seem to recall what the name was (or which paper I read it in), and it's driving me mad.

This is a silly question, granted, but I would appreciate it if anyone who knows a standard (or just a sensible) name for this group could kindly remind me what it is.  If I recall right, the name it was supposed to call to mind the isomorphism $\text{SO}(4) \cong (\text{SU}(2) \times \text{SU}(2))/\mathbb{Z}_2$.  Thanks.

Comment: Presumably you have in mind the diagonal action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: yes, the diagonal action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $SU(2)\times SU(2) = \operatorname{Spin}(4)$ so

$$(SU(2)\times SU(2)\times SU(2))/\mathbb{Z}_2 \cong (\operatorname{Spin}(4)\times SU(2))/\mathbb{Z}_2$$

which is sometimes called $\operatorname{Spin}^h(4)$. It is also referred to as $\operatorname{Spin}_{SU(2)}(4)$, see for example $(2.15)$ of [*A New $SU(2)$ Anomaly*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.00844) by Wang, Wen, and Witten.

Comment: thank you, Michael!  you wouldn't happen to have a reference (any paper at all) for the nomenclature $\text{Spin}^h(4)$, would you?

Comment: There's definition 5 (page 24) of [Xuan Chen's thesis](https://web.archive.org/web/20180708075517/https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/alumni/2017-Xuan-Chen.pdf). In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.01886.pdf), they denote the group by $G_0(4)$, see the bottom of page 65. You might also be interested in [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/304471/21564).